# Invariant mass in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass, collision, invariants

I'm following a special relativity course and I'm trying to understand how the invariant mass works. In particular I don't get how the following passages work.

We have a collision between two particles and I get that the invariant mass is the sum squared of the 4-momenta. I also get the second passage, but I don't understand how to go through the last passage, in particular where each piece comes from.

Could you please help me? Thanks! :)

$$M^2 = (p^{\mu}_1 + p^{\mu}_2)^2 = (p^{\mu}_1)^2 + (p^{\mu}_2)^2 + 2 p^{\mu}_1 p_{\mu 2} = m_1^2 + m_2^2 + 2(E_1E_2 - \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{p}_2)$$

Comment: Do you know what are the components of the 4-momentum $p_\mu$?

Comment: Yes they are (E/c, p_x, p_y, p_z)

Comment: Ok i think i got it, it should be because p²_mu=E²-p²=m² and for the last term from matrix multiplication

Comment: So when can we just use p²_mu=m²

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @KyleKanos ok for next time I will know, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, if you have two four vectors $A^\mu=(A^0,\vec{A})$, $B^\mu=(B^0,\vec{B})$ then their Minkowski four-product is
$$
A^\mu B_\mu = A^0B^0-\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}.
$$

In your case particle 1 you have that
$$
(p_1^\mu)^2 \equiv P_1^\mu P_{1\mu}=E_1^2-\vec{p}_1^2 =m_1^2
$$
(I used the shorthand $\vec{p}^2\equiv\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}$). The same holds for particle 2 so that the first two terms should be ok. The last term is
$$
p_1^\mu p_{2\mu} = E_1E_2-\vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{p}_2
$$